# Coin tossing heads-counting game probabilities

Tags: probability, summation, binomial-distribution

Suppose I have a coin for which the probability of heads is $p$. Now suppose I have a two-player game where the first player may flip this coin $m$ times and the second player may flip this coin $n$ times, and the player who gets the most heads wins.

I'm trying to determine the probability that the first player wins if $m$, $n$, and $p$ are known.  Suppose $P(n, k, p)$ is the binomial probability mass function and $C(n, k, p)$ is the binomial cumulative distribution function.  It would then seem that the probability of a first player win would be $\sum^m_{x=1}P(m,x,p)C(n,x-1,p)$ and the probability of a draw would be $\sum^k_{x=0}P(m,x,p)P(n,x,p)$, where $k$ is the smaller of $m$ and $n$.  Are either of these expressible without the use of summation notation?

Also, is there a general name for the distribution that ensues from this (a categorial distribution where probabilities are determined by binomial distributions)?

Comment: What happens if the number of heads happen to be the same?

Comment: That would be a draw.  If we wanted to repeat the process until there is a clear winner, the probability of the first player winning would clearly be $p/(p+q)$, where $p$ is the probability of the first player winning (under the original definition) and $q$ is the probability of the first player losing (under the original definition).

Comment: What you've done seems to be correct.